# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denied in reading from external storage

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I already added

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

in manifest.xml, but it shows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.selectmultipleimages_demo/com.selectmultipleimages_demo.CustomGallery_Activity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=5290, uid=10149 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission() exception
```

Comment: can you share you manifest file

Comment: In Android 6.0+ the permission system has changed.

Comment: where is write permission? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed by Android Version API 23 onwards, ie Marshmallow onward you need to get run time permission to access user's confidential data. Run time permissions is clearly explained here : [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Also, this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/4738175) shall help you to implement run time permission for the purpose of writing to the External Storage.